# How to show an integral of a complex function is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, analytic-functions

The question is, with an interval $I=[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, as well as a function $f:I\to\mathbb{C}$ how to show the following function: $$F(z)=\int_a^b\frac{f(t)}{t-z}\,dt$$ is analytic on the domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus I$?

I just want to know the best procedure to do so. I guess I should use the definition of the complex derivative, but not sure if I need to solve the integral as a function of $t$ first.

Comment: Use differentiation under the integral sign. See Lang, Complex Analysis, 3rd edition, Chapter XV, Section 1, Lemma 1.1.

Comment: A more general version of this proved in Rudin's RCA. Also this question has appeared many times on this site.

Comment: int: Try Morera's theorem.